How to use post method if the BLOC provider of current page didn't have any create class
When using BLOC Provider, we need to call the BLOC class along with the service that needs to be loaded when the new page is being called. In that same BLOC listener, we can use the POST method and listen to the response.
But I need to use BLOC and only the POST method. Please help
How to use the BLOC pattern to add only the POST method.
Here is my code
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: false,
      ),
      home: const LoginPage(),
    );
  }
}

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<LoginPage> createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  TextEditingController userName = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController password = TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            const Text("User Name"),
            TextField(
              controller: userName,
            ),
            const Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
              child: Text("Password"),
            ),
            TextField(
              controller: password,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      debugPrint(
                          "UserName - ${userName.text}\nPassword - ${password.text}");
                      // Need to call BLOC Method
                    },
                    child: const Text('Login'),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


Can you add a minimal code example of your issue? It is hard to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

@quoci I am trying to use the BLOC method. When I try to use BLOC we need a BLOC Provider and BLOC Liserner. If my BLOC class contains only the POST method, I can't able to initiate the BLOC Provider.
